# paper.js - achieving smoother edges with closed paths

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

This is a box with an irregular shape that I have generated:

[image]

And this is the end effect I'd like to achieve (note the smooth edges):

[image]

Here's the code for my sharp version:

```
var path1 = new Path({
    segments: [[123, 6], [290, 6], [304, 142], [112, 142]],
    strokeColor: 'white',
    closed: true,
    strokeWidth: 3,
    strokeJoin: 'round'
});
```

Thing is, I'm already using the **strokeJoin: 'round'** option and the difference is hardly noticeable with a stroke width of 3px. It's a small thing but could turn into a game breaker as there are going to be multiple objects like this and the difference is huge.

Is there any way to achieve that with paper.js without overdoing it?

Comment: `strokeJoin` only determines how the intersection point of 2 lines will be displayed. Since it's a point it won't result in a curve.  So you will need to use both lines & curves (or arcs) to round your trapezoid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As markE mentioned, `strokeJoin` only changes the canvas style of a path's stroke. Paper.js does not come with a corner-rounding function, you'll have to make your own.

Here's a quick function that you can use a starting point. It will negatively offset the points of a polygon by a given distance and add the appropriate handles.

```
function roundPath(path,radius) {
    var segments = path.segments.slice(0);
    path.segments = [];
    for(var i = 0, l = segments.length; i < l; i++) {
        var curPoint = segments[i].point;
        var nextPoint = segments[i + 1 == l ? 0 : i + 1].point;
        var prevPoint = segments[i - 1 < 0 ? segments.length - 1 : i - 1].point;
        var nextDelta = curPoint - nextPoint;
        var prevDelta = curPoint - prevPoint;
        nextDelta.length = radius;
        prevDelta.length = radius;
        path.add({
            point:curPoint - prevDelta,
            handleOut: prevDelta/2
        });
        path.add({
            point:curPoint - nextDelta,
            handleIn: nextDelta/2
        });
    }
    path.closed = true;
    return path;
}
```

[Here it is in action.](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/lVRNj5swEP0rIy4LDSEQqRey0R52VamHqivtoYeQgxcmixXHRsawrVb8944NBfLRw3IA+c2b92bGNh+eZCf0Uu/liCYvvdDLVWHXLdNQG3ptQeI7PDNT+sEmkxbXrOBN/YsXpqRwEhOcydUKHjUyg8BcRl2yCgFb1H/goMnEUZgsQNU5F8IyTYlzsUweGpkbriQo+c3m+JQvTfCRSaDH1hNpPKkWXS0W69OpDP8HlRjVXPY5Ua4aaVbrOFgkwZeZyWbSmvUWvdDaH3zsk5MG6hRaju9RvwinaKW4NHUKydcZ2JskhMbxFby25DlcG62O+KiEIpe7V8Hy410f7YLzGjV1UrgNsEA4CFpSZwc/zmziVfQKBxpQU5lx24lvJ2rEDqtysxrWUS14jn5sFTNzFiLqbu/gg9K+FeEExSEI+oz5AuUbDZZi9yDos1gMrr1v3uhnO69Zyo7vIzfDzUST+Ntc82ABCWy3ZPgAMaTggOvkSmN7I3lJyfeU93BZrItYteUtNVvKEwrDSG2sfjlVeGF8gzrWM1BHxX/+22Ebh/go87+43RVWFPMjOh7E9MLYCYXnxJJunsCfjUknymrdi3fBZ13Gdm66fJfpxLgw6cYzlgtVY0GNGt2gi2k0jZbucNrDTT+jV/qjHPvL5qW7ffcX)

Comment: Works amazingly well and does EXACTLY what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: @winduptoy unfortunately your link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for an exact implementation, as described here: http://shanfanhuang.com/everything/2015/10/27/rounding-corners

My implementation works as follows:

- curPoint is the corner, prevPoint and nextPoint as above
- nextNorm and prevNorm are the normalized versions of the points
- angle is the angle of the corner, derived from the dot product
- delta is the distance from the corner points to where the control points need to be inserted, this is derived from a right triangle formed by the control point, curPoint and the center of the corner arc. The corner is a half angle, and the side opposing that corner is the radius
- prevDelta and nextDelta are the new endpoints of the sides, between those an arc is inserted
- through is a point halfway on the arc, found by getting the hypotenuse of the above triangle and subtracting the radius.

  ```
  var segments = path.segments.slice(0);
  path.segments = [];
  for(var i = 0, l = segments.length; i < l; i++) {
      var curPoint = segments[i].point;
      var nextPoint = segments[i + 1 == l ? 0 : i + 1].point;
      var prevPoint = segments[i - 1 < 0 ? segments.length - 1 : i - 1].point;

      var nextNorm = (curPoint - nextPoint).normalize();
      var prevNorm = (curPoint - prevPoint).normalize();

      var angle = Math.acos(nextNorm.dot(prevNorm));

      var delta = radius/Math.tan(angle/2);
      var prevDelta = prevNorm.normalize(delta);
      var nextDelta = nextNorm.normalize(delta);

      var through = curPoint - (prevNorm + nextNorm).normalize(Math.sqrt(delta*delta + radius*radius) - radius);

      path.add(curPoint - prevDelta);
      path.arcTo(through, curPoint - nextDelta);
  }
  ```